# Replacing cell values with blank

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I am trying to replace cell value `N/A` on my spreadsheet with a blank value.

I have tried various different `replace` formats that I have found online.

```
if preferredphonenumber == 'N/A':
    replace = df1[rownum, 20].replace('N/A', 'blank', inplace=True, regex=True )
    print(replace)
else:
    print(df1)
```

I'm expecting the N/A value to be replaced with "blank".

error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2890, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: (8, 20)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nickkeith2/Desktop/PBMS/PBMS/PBMS.py", line 17, in <module>
    replace = df1[rownum, 20].replace('N/A', 'blank', inplace=True, regex=True )
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2975, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2892, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: (8, 20)
```

Comment: can you show your DataFrame `df1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace all the cells that have "N/A" with "", then you can just use

```
df.replace("N/A","", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

If you want to replace "N/A" with "" in just one column, you can use

```
df['Column_Name'].replace("N/A","", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

If you want to replace "N/A" with "" in just one particular cell, you can use

```
df.at['X', 'Y'] = 10 
df.set_value('X', 'Y', 10)
#in both of the above cases you are technically assigning a new value to the cell, X is row , Y is column
```

Comment: How do you print our export your results? When I am printing it is just returning "N/A None".

Comment: You mean printing the dataframe with the new values? If yes do print(df)